# This.SetState is not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authorization

I know that perhaps the problem lies within the functions held inside the main login function but I cannot catch it. It returns this error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setState')

```js
export default class Main extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      logged: null,
      name: "Felicia"
    };
  }
  login(e){
    const email = document.getElementById('txtEmail').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('txtPass').value;
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          console.log("There is a user logged");
          console.log(user.email);
          this.setState({ name: firebase.auth.currentUser.displayName, logged: "true" })
        } else {
          console.log("No user Logged");
        }
      }).bind(this)

render(){
if(this.state.logged){
  return <Student name={this.state.name} />
} else {
  return (
    <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-6 loginform">
    <input type="email" id="txtEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="email@email.co.uk" />
    <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">Well never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    <input type="password" id="txtPass" className="form-control" placeholder="password"/>
    <button onClick={this.login} className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}
  }
}
```

Could you please help me solving this problem?

Comment: Did you try to check if `firebase.auth.currentUser` is available?

Comment: When are you calling the function login() in the code?

Comment: @Jay there is a button with onClick function returned if the currentUser = null

Comment: @Umesh I have tried with `if(firebase.auth.currentUser != null){ this.setState...}` but it returned the same error.

Comment: @PRvn do a console.log and check what is the value of firebase.auth.currentUser.displayName, also please share the snippet where you are calling the function

Comment: @Jay so I added `console.log(firebase.auth.currentUser)` and it returns null

Comment: @Jay but I've just tried with `firebase.auth().currentUser.email` and it returns the e-mail

Comment: @PRvn so there is a definite issue in the way that your doing it, your trying to get value from DOM in React, which are two different entities, to get the value of the input elements, I would suggest using the [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) pattern as described in React Docs, also please bind the login function in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

You are not binding the callback function to this. You should bind callback function of `onAuthStateChanged` to `this` like

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((function(user) {
     ...
}).bind(this))
```

Comment: he seems to have bind it

Comment: @Jay Yeah but not the callback of `onAuthStateChanged`

Comment: I've just added it but it still returns the same error.

Comment: @PRvn Remove `bind(this)` and try converting `function(user) {` to `(user) => {` Want to see if it is binding issue or not.

Comment: @Prakashsharma it worked! Thank you so much! Could you please tell me how it affected the flow so I can avoid this in the future?